# iOS Thread Isolation

Tags: ios, multithreading, mobile, isolation

I have some general questions to iOS Threads. According to Apple all Threads share the same memory space (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)
Is it possible (for security reasons) that each thread has it's own memory an communication is done via messaging?

Flutter has it's own concept of isolates and they say that these threads don't share the memory. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html
How are they doing this? I mean, Dart is later compiled to native code, which means it should be possible natively as well.

The same applies for Xamarin and their AppDomains which can be used for Isolation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=xamarinios-10.8

Comment: Look at the manual page for fork(2)

Comment: Which part exactly? And fork is not something that is available in iOS programming as far as I know.

Comment: weird; ios is darwin, which is unix, and fork is integral to unix.   Regardless, the point was more abstract -- a thread with a protected address space is usually known as a process.